Pull Request link not showing in Visual Studio 2022
We have an Azure DevOps Server 2022 update 2, and a source working with Visual Studio 2022 version 17.11.6.
The repository's source control is Git in the DevOps server.
The push operations don't have any issue, but when we push any source, the Pull Request link is not showing up in Visual Studio (does not exist in any menus).
The authentication of users, uses Active Directory. Also when we work on another source in GitHub, the link exists and works correctly.
